# R/Shiny App Writes Plots to Plot View in RStudio Instead of Shiny UI

Tags: r, plot, shiny, rstudio, reactive

I have a Shiny app with a plotOutput component:

```
  plotOutput("plot_data")
```

Using the vis_dat library, I write to plot_data as follows:

```
  observeEvent(input$missing, { # Click the Missing actionButton
    v$plot_data <- vis_miss(new_data())
    })
```

and...

```
  output$plot_data <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$plot_data)) return()
    v$plot_data
  })
```

It works fine. Now, I also (try to) write to the same component using the pairs() function, like so:

```
  observeEvent(input$pairs, {  # Click the Pairs actionButton
    v$plot_data <- pairs(new_data()) 
    })
```

I use the same reactive output$plot_data call as shown before, but this time, the pairs() output writes a plot to the RStudio plot panel instead of the Shiny UI. I have seen this with other types of plots, too. Any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

Charting functions in R such as `hist()`, `plot()`, and `pairs()` render images, not plots. So I used the `renderImage()` function as follows:

```
  output$image_data <- renderImage({
    width  <- session$clientData$output_image_data_width
    height <- session$clientData$output_image_data_height
    
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
    png(outfile, width=width, height=height)
    plot(new_data(), pch=20 , cex=1.5 , col="#69b3a2")
    dev.off()
    
    list(
      src = outfile,
      width = width,
      height = height
      )
    }, 
  deleteFile = TRUE
  )
```

In RStudio it all looks like plots, but the returns are not equal.